# xml-tei in R: length(nodes) with one different value

Tags: r, xml, tei

Sorry, there is not enough documentation for parsing xml-tei in R yet, especially for a beginner in R.

I am counting several nodes with function 'getNodeSet' which have only one different value in 'contains'. The aim is to count '@type=verb' according to specific 'contains' which has all in commun 'contains(@ana,'#action')'. Examples:

```
#different value "@ana, '#displacement'" 
nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//ns:w[contains(@type,'verb') and contains(@ana,'#action') and contains(@ana, '#displacement') and contains(@ana, '#ANT')]", ns)  
VARIABLE NAME01 <- length(nodes)
VARIABLE NAME01
#result in the console [2] 

#different value "@ana, '#put_together'" 
nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//ns:w[contains(@type,'verb') and contains(@ana,'#action') and contains(@ana, '#put_together') and  contains(@ana, '#ANT')]", ns)
VARIABLE NAME02 <- length(nodes) 
VARIABLE NAME02
#result in the console [0]

#different value "@ana, '#destruction'" 
nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//ns:w[contains(@type,'verb') and contains(@ana,'#action') and contains(@ana, '#destruction') and contains(@ana, '#ANT')]", ns)
VARIABLE NAME03 <- length(nodes)
VARIABLE NAME03
#result in the console [7]
```

But it is of course very tedious to write each time basically the same things and it's not very beautiful.

Is it possible to have something like (sorry, not propertly encoded, just an example to follow my need):

```
#a condition
For node=getNodeSet(doc,"//ns:w[contains(@type,'verb') and contains(@ana,'#action') and not(contains(@ana, '#ANT'))]" 
#add in contains
(    
(@ana, ‘DIFFERENT VALUE01') FOR VARIABLE01
(@ana, ‘DIFFERENT VALUE02') FOR VARIABLE02
(@ana, ‘DIFFERENT VALUE03') FOR VARIABLE03
)
#etc.
```

Do you have an idea?

After, I need to be able to add the result:

```
add_result <- sum(VARIABLE NAME01, VARIABLE NAME02, VARIABLE NAME03)
add_result
```

But then, I was thinking of:

```
nodes=sum(
 (getNodeSet(doc,"//ns:w[contains(@ana,'#action') and contains(@type,'verb')]", ns)),
 (getNodeSet(doc,"//ns:w[contains(@type,'verb') and contains(@type,'verb')]", ns))
 )
add_result <- length(nodes) 
add_result
```

and then I look for the other node with a different value.
But sadly, it doesn't work.

In advance, thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What I did so far:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague, 'R' specialist, helped me and proposed:

```
typeAction=c("'#displacement'","'#put_together'","'#agression'","'#confrontation'","'#movement'","'#otherAction'")
total_action_ANT=0
for (i in 1:length(typeAction)) total_action_ANT=total_action_ANT+length(getNodeSet(doc,paste0("//ns:w[contains(@type,'verb') and contains(@ana,'#action') and contains(@ana, ",typeAction[i],") and contains(@ana, '#ANT')]"), ns))
total_action_ANT

nodelist=list()
for (i in 1:length(typeAction))nodelist[[i]]=getNodeSet(doc,paste0("//ns:w[contains(@type,'verb') and contains(@ana,'#action') and contains(@ana, ",typeAction[i],") and contains(@ana, '#ANT')]"), ns)
str(nodelist)
resultats = cbind(action=typeAction,occurences=unlist(lapply(nodelist,function(x)length(x))))
resultats
```

It works great! Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

What I did so far:

```
nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//ns:w[contains(@type,'verb') and contains(@ana,'#action') and contains(@ana, '#displacement') and contains(@ana, '#ANT')]", ns)
nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//ns:w[contains(@type,'verb') and contains(@ana,'#action') and contains(@ana, '#put_together') and  contains(@ana, '#ANT')]", ns)
VARIABLE NAME01 <- length(nodes)
VARIABLE NAME02 <- length(nodes)
```

Don't know if there is a more simple way to do it.